# How to ask facebook to **prescrape** my page information

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Users post quite a log of images on our website, we prepare OpenGraph tags with thubs per recommendations in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices yet whenever user shares the image for the very first time, he often sees zero preview. Final share is usually fine, 2nd sharing is also fine.

Debugging in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing tells that our images are either over 8MB or take too long to load. Yet they are always around 100-300KB and even the first request ever to fetch them takes some 300ms (depends on the CDN node you are in, but definitely not a second).

So my guess is that facebook crawler actually needs some time to process the downloaded image and it can take time.

**Can we somehow ask facebook to "prescrape" the page, to tell that this page is likely to be shared?**

I was trying to use rescrape call for it, but it results in nothing as the fresh link was never shared yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by making a POST request to https://graph.facebook.com with the following parameters:

- id: URL to scrape
- scrape: true

A simple example with jQuery:

```
$.post('https://graph.facebook.com', {
    id: 'https://yourdomain.com/yoururl',
    scrape: true
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Of course you can do this with PHP curl too, here´s more information about that: [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

If you want to do it with JavaScript, i suggest using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).